# Firebase storage rules error: unexpected identifier; function taken from documentation

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using firebase and am trying to make the storage publicly accessible. According to the firebase documentation I need to include the following code, which I added to the .js file which contains a function that sends user input to storage.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Based off others' problems I've tried:

- adding ;-s
- changing it to firebase.storage(code),
- doing var storage ...

but none of these methods work.

I have my code for configuring firebase (apiKey, authDomain, databaseURL, projectID, and storageBucket) and also initialized the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't code that you would put in a JS file, this is a [firebase storage security rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start).  It is a configuration that you  would configure in the console for your project (alternatively, you can deploy the rules via the CLI, but they are still not a direct part of your application code).

You should navigate to the rules tab and input the configuration there:

[image: image from firebase console of the rules setting]

Of course, **the rule you are suggesting here is very dangerous**!

This rule will allow any user (including unauthenticated users!) to write as much as they want into your storage bucket -- effectively giving you the bill for their free storage.  You should consider carefully if this is what you really want.